# wso2is on multiple hostnames

Tags: authentication, saml, wso2-identity-server

considering to deploy WSO2 IS as a SAML IdP. However - users need to access / authenticate from two separate networks - from the internal private network and external (public) internet. Users from the private network have no access to internet. Effectively - the WSO2 IS will be accessed by several (two) hostnames.

The problem we have is, The /samlsso endpoint redirects user to the endpoint defined in repository/conf/identity.xml as SSOService/IdentityProviderURL.

Thus - one group of user will have no access to the authentication endpoint.

One solution would be having a separate instance for the internal and external access using the same user store, but - is there a way to use a single configuration?

Thank you in advance for any tip.

Gabriel

Comment: Just a consideration - wouldn't a tenant per hostname solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible (wso2is-5.0.0) out of box

seeing the source code of the AuthnRequestProcessor, a configured URL is enforced

```
                // Validate 'Destination'
                String idpUrl = IdentityUtil.getProperty(IdentityConstants.ServerConfig.SSO_IDP_URL);

                if (authnReqDTO.getDestination() == null
                        || !idpUrl.equals(authnReqDTO.getDestination())) {
                    String msg = "Destination validation for Authentication Request failed. " +
                                    "Received: [" + authnReqDTO.getDestination() + "]." +
                                    " Expected: [" + idpUrl + "]";
                    log.warn(msg);
                    return buildErrorResponse(authnReqDTO.getId(),
                            SAMLSSOConstants.StatusCodes.REQUESTOR_ERROR, msg);
```